# Identifying records via Batch Apex timing out. REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG

Tags: soql, batch, timeout

I'm trying to identify task records in a production org. The problem is that the data volume is too large to create a report or one-off SOQL Task records. Our task records are huge and are in desperate cleanup, hence us needing to identify certain information before proceeding with mass deletions. There are 1907144 task records (3.6 GB) and 40% of our data usage.

So I thought I would try a batch SOQL to buy more processing time. However I'm getting the following error:

> First error: [REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG] Your request was running for too long, and has been stopped.

I've tried multiple methods of speeding up the query by adding or removing filter criteria, but it always seems to timeout in Production. Putting a limit on the SOQL doesn't seem to help either. Is there something I can change in the batch class to increase the timeout limit or could I add or remove parts of my filter criteria? Note: the Subject LIKE '%Opportunity has been%' is really what I am trying to identify and needs to be in the query somewhere.

Here's my relevant code (edited per Eric's comment below, but it still failed :(

```
global class batchableSOQL implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{

    global List<String> taskRecordIds = new List<String>();
    global String s;
    global List<String> stringLines = new List<String>();

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        //String twoYearsAgo =  DateTime.now().AddDays(-730).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'z\'');
        String query = 'select id, subject, type, ActivityDate, WhatId, What.name, CreatedDate from Task WHERE contains_Opportunity_has_been__c  = true  AND Type = \'System Generated Email\' AND Isdeleted = false AND CreatedDate > 2015-05-22T00:00:00Z';
    System.Debug('queryis= '+query);
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Task> scope){
        //add the found records to a csv
    } 

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        //notify admin of records found with csv attachment
    }

}
```

Comment: Fyi there's an `addYears` method...

Comment: The major issue is in these two filters only: `LIKE \'%Opportunity has been%\' AND Subject LIKE \'%A Related%\'` . Try if you can change into some thing else.

Comment: One thing I have done when I needed to filter based on "LIKE" for a one off process is create a formula field checkbox to be true if the LIKE condition is met. Then in the query use that checkbox = true. In reality it is still a full table scan IIRC but seems to get one over the hump in situations like these. no guarantee it will work in your specific case though but may be worth a try...

Comment: Eric, that's a great suggestion and I tried it again and it still failed... I'm going to try querying in chunks of months manually and gathering the results and report back. For example: where contains_Opportunity_has_been__c = true AND createdDate >= 2016-09-20T00:00:00Z and createdDate <= 2016-12-20T00:00:00Z

Comment: I have also seen where batch queries will fail and the error gets thrown in SF own query locator class and not the batch. In those cases I ended up querying the entire table without filters and processed them in the execute method filtering them there. I am confident that will work if you can make it fit into your design

Comment: How about dataloader ? If your intention is to cleanup..do you process any logic in execute ?

Comment: Couple of things, no need for the is deleted and use a SOQL constant for the date. May help. I would also include the type as a part of the formula field and not in the query: `select id, subject, type, ActivityDate, WhatId, What.name, CreatedDate from Task WHERE contains_Opportunity_has_been__c  = true  AND CreatedDate = LAST_N_YEARS:2'` and put the Type = \'System Generated Email\' as part of the formula or filter it in the execute portion. you want to get your query as generic as possible. you may need to remove the formula as well and filter in execute

Comment: I  second data loader as a much more sensible tool for the job.

Comment: Can't even begin to use dataloader unless we gather the record ids, that is why I'm going down this path to identity the records.

Comment: Have you checked out the Storage Minder product on the AppExchange? It can both Archive old tasks or just delete them - with any number of filters.